# Select specific id when using group by function [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I have the following example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb6b3c/9)

The `ID`s returned are for 'August'. However, I want the `ID`s for September.

The `group by` function selects the first `id` available.

How can I do this?

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's extended GROUP BY feature.. Making it possible to select column with are not in the MySQL. Causing invalid data for the select columns which are not in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Because of the `id` field?